# Pseudo class :hover does not work in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've got such a simple code:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Foo</div>
  <div class="div3">
    <div class="div4">
      <div class="div5">
        Bar
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```css
.div1{
  position: relative;
}
.div1 .div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
}
.div1:hover .div3 {
  display: block;
}
.div2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: green;
  color: #000;  
}
.div5 {}
```

The problem is: When I move the cursor from `.div2` to `.div3` (`.div3` should stay visible because it's the child of `.div1`) then the hover is disabled. I'm testing it in IE7, in FF it works fine. What am I doing wrong? I've also realized that when i remove `.div5` tag than it's working. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that it may be the case that you need to also add .div3:hover{ display: block } otherwise when you move your mouse over the child element .div3 the parent will lose its pseudo class :hover. This depends on your implementation however.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

IE7 won't allow you to apply `:hover` pseudo-classes to non-anchor elements unless you explicitly specify a doctype. Just add a doctype declaration to your page and it should work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

More on IE7/quirks mode can be found on [this blog post](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution worked better and was a bit cleaner:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .wrapper {

        }

        .trigger {
            background: #223;
        }

        .appear {
            background: #334;
            display: none;
        }

        .trigger:hover .appear {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="trigger">
            <p>This is the trigger for the hover element.</p>
            <div class="appear">
                <p>I'm <strong>alive!</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

[pastebin](http://paste2.org/p/79237).

Comment: This is “cleaner” than specifying a DOCTYPE?  How so?

Comment: @mkoistinen Note that this was posted 14 hours before the DOCTYPE answer, which I did not know about at the time :)

Comment: Ah, my bad, I should have looked at the dates to figure out the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the double margin problem?
I did an display: inline-block when it happened for a li
http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html