# Internet Explorer drop down menu problem!

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, menu

I created a drop-down menu for web-site. But apparently,this drop-down menu just works in Firefox not in IE.

So What's wrong? Can anyone tell me this? Or give me an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: the ones after IE7 mostly, including IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support the :hover pseudo-class on anything other than anchor tags.  You'll need to use Javascript to make this work in IE.

Edit: As corrected by Kolink, this is an untrue statement for IE7+.  IE7+ will need to be rendering in standards compliant mode to support it though.  That means you'll need a doctype header on your HTML. See [Pseudo class :hover does not work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/problem-with-hover-in-ie7)

Comment: This is incorrect. Or it might have been correct in IE6, but it's certainly not true of IE7 and up.

Comment: Ah good point.  I deal with IE6 so much still that I forgot.  You do need a strict doctype to allow it to work in IE7 at least.

Comment: Dude, you are perfect. THis link you gave solve the problem for me. The power of Searching :D. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed these `<div>`s and other tags inside a `<tr>`, without using a `<td>`. This is invalid HTML and non-IE browsers are covering your back.

Comment: Actually I put a td tag too. But nothing is changed. My dropdown menu still doesn't drop down. :S.