# Custom Tooltip didn't work on IE

Tags: html, css, tooltip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with :hover in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/problem-with-hover-in-ie7)

I created a following custom tooltip with html and css.

It is HTML.

```
<a class="ttp" id="HelpIcon">
<img src="HelpIcon.gif" alt="" />
<div class="tooltip" id="ToolTipContainer">
sf sfsfs fsf fsd fsdfsf f  skfksf sfs fskfsak fskldflsa fksafks afskladflkasf slkaf skfjskl  fsjfl sflsf a </div>
</a>
```

It is CSS.

/*Simple Hover No URL*/

```
a.ttp {
                position:relative;
                z-index:24;
                color:#3ca3ff;
                font-weight:normal;
                font-size:11px;
                font-family:Lucida Grande, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-decoration:none;
                cursor:default;
            }

            a.ttp div {
                display:none;
            }

            a.ttp:hover {
                z-index:25;
                color:#aaaaff;
            }

            a.ttp:hover div.tooltip {
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
                top:3px;
                padding:10px 0 0 0;
                left:20px;
                background-image:url(HoverImage.gif);
                color:#993300;
                text-align: center;
                filter: alpha(opacity:90);
                -moz-opacity:0.9;
                -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
                overflow:hidden;
                width:200px;
                height:120px;
            }
```

I got a problem. That is working fine on chrome and firefox. But it not OK IE. How can I solve it.

Comment: I see it in IE 8, which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but have you considered the open source tooltip options ? should be more cross browser stable?  For example. http://mojavelinux.com/projects/domtooltip/

Answer (score 1):

Specify an appropriate doctype for your markup. IE won't play friendly with :hover when in quirks mode.

Comment: More detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/problem-with-hover-in-ie7