# Show/Hide Button in Table Row during mouseover

Tags: jquery, html-table, mouseover, jquery-hover

I have a table of rows (duh) and in one of the columns, I'm trying to have two buttons appear during hover/mouseover.  Right now, it's an anchor tag with a set width/height and a background placement.

This is what they appear like when not hidden:

[image]

A good example of the finished product is grooveshark's hover controls:

[image]

Basically I'm wondering how I would go about getting all the images to be hidden except the ones in a row that is currently being hovered over. Then that row would show those images but disappear once the mouse moves to a different row.

Html Code:

```
echo '<td><a href="/servers/detail.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">'.$row['server_name'].'</a><a id="option-favorite" class="rowOption"></a><a id="option-vote" class="rowOption"></a></td>';
```

JS Code:

```
jQuery('td').live('mouseover', function () {
    jQuery(this).closest("tr").find('a.rowOption').visible();
});
```

Comment: `visible()` is not a jquery function...Oh, and `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you have tables of rows (duh) you can use CSS like this:

```
  table#mytableofrows tr td a.button { display:none;}
  table#mytableofrows tr:hover td a.button { display:inline-block;}
```

Will work for this markup:

```
<table id="mytableofrows" width="100%">
    <tr><td> <a class="button">Hello yes this is dog</a> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, changed it a bit but worked exactly as needed! For anyone interested, final code was: http://pastebin.com/H8x8r0vW

Comment: Nice anims. :) Note that `:hover` won't work in IE6. In IE7 it will work but you need to put a doctype (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/problem-with-hover-in-ie7).

Answer (score 7):

Try using HTML5 style tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table tr button { opacity:0; float:right }
      table tr:hover button { opacity:1 }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border=1 width=300px>
      <tr><td>LINE1 <button>BUTTON1</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td>LINE2 <button>BUTTON2</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td>LINE3 <button>BUTTON3</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```