# Text color can't change when hover a button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the text color of the button when mouse over a button    
  **here is *my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/yQEQJ/)***

My Html Is

```
<div id="groups_landingpage_contentdiv">        
    <div class="groups_landingpage_contentdiv_image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/F1s05.png" width="150" />
    </div>
    <div class="groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text">
        <h2>Welcome To Rang De Group</h2>
        <p>RDBO conducts free screenings of rare, socially relevant 
           documentaries and films for the general public and corporate audiences.  
            <button class="landingpage_create_group_button">
                <span class="sprite_16x16_group_icon_with_circleback fl mar5"></span>
                <p>Create A Group</p>
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>            
    <div class="clearfloat"> </div>
</div>`
```

My Css Is

```
.sprite_16x16_group_icon_with_circleback {
    background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/On0lt.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-position:-250px -524px;
    height:34px;
    width:41px
}

.fl {
    float:left
}

.mar5 {
    margin:5px
}

#groups_landingpage_contentdiv {
    float:left;
    width:727px;
    padding:0 0 20px!important
}

.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_image {
    float:left;
    width:35%;
    padding:25px 0 0 20px
}

.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text {
    float:left;
    width:55%;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:20px 0 0
}

.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text h2 {
    color:#628e0e;
    font:11pt/22pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:600;
    padding:0 0 10px
}

.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p {
    color:#404040;
    font:9pt/16pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:0
}

.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p button.landingpage_create_group_button p {
    font-size:11pt;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#000;
    line-height:18px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;
    padding:9px 0 0!important
}

.landingpage_create_group_button {
    background:#F8F8F8;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10pt;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    line-height:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 7px 3px
}

.landingpage_create_group_button:hover {
    background:#9ABA3B;
    color:#fff!important;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #6F862A
}

.landingpage_create_group_button:hover.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p button.landingpage_create_group_button p {
    color:#fff!important;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #6F862A
}
```

Comment: Please fix your post, this is difficult to read without proper formatting.

Comment: I assume by the tags that you want and know you'll need js to change the button text, but you include no js/jquery at all. It would help if you were a bit more clear in asking your question.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify a bit, is it that you trying to change the text *color* or text *content*? `I am trying to change the text of the button when mouse over a button ` is a bit vague

Comment: Actually i am trying to change the text color only not the text

Comment: @SureshPattu I removed the jquery/javascript tag as it is not related to your problem. Feel free to accept an answer if you prroblem has been solved.

Comment: @Christoph Sure i will up your answer. Thanks a lot for answering my question :)

Comment: then my poor answer should work as it was originally :( :( :( :( glad you got an answer anyway :)

Comment: @NiftyDude Hi actually after you answered my question i plan to accept Your answer as the best answer. then suddenly the answer disappear. Now I accepted your Answer is the best answer thank you so much :)

Comment: Hey no prob, glad I could help ;)

Comment: @NiftyDude no offense, but I think although you correctly state that it's an specificit issue, your answer is bad for the following reasons: 1. You just add another rule - thats wrong, since refactoring the first rule would be the right choice. 2. You don't remove the `!important` although it's unnecessary and not recommended to use. 3. You add unnecessary specificity to the hover selector, by prepending `button` which impacts the performance and can be omitted anyway.

Comment: SureshPattu please accept @Christoph answer since he's more correct :)

Comment: @SureshPattu great :) everyone's happy now I suppose :D

Comment: @NiftyDude Good that's what i also want now i am also very happy :) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: You dont need javascript/jquery for this!! (And please don't do it, because that's a lot of uneccessary work)

You just have to watch out for [selector specifity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Also, always try to avoid `!important`. It is meant to clear conflicts between author and user stylesheets, not to fix your messy CSS!

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEQJ/11/) see your code working.

I just reduced the specifity of your initial selector from:

```
.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p button.landingpage_create_group_button p
```

to

```
.landingpage_create_group_button p
```

and changed your hover selector from

```
.landingpage_create_group_button:hover.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p button.landingpage_create_group_button p
```

(what the heck is this) to

```
.landingpage_create_group_button:hover p
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: Hi this working fine. now i understand what's the problem also, thank you so much for clarifying my doubt :)

Comment: @SureshPattu Glad I could help. I recommend you to read into CSS-Selectors. Writing good CSS-selectors is key in bigger projects or you will lose control very soon.

Comment: @SureshPattu are you looking to change the text inside the button, or *just* the font color...?

Comment: I realised exactly the same: it is about font style. Not however that CSS :hover on DIV elements doesn't work in (older versions) of IE

Comment: @Jochem well, it doesn't work in IE6-. As long as you are not developing huge Enterprise Software based on IE6 you can ignore that (IE6 has <1% Marketshare in the World exluding China)

Comment: Actually i am trying to change the text color only not the text

Comment: @Christoph true point. I vaguely remembered running into it once with IE7 but apparently one can get it to work in IE7 by supplying a doctype. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/problem-with-hover-in-ie7

Answer (score 4):

Because your text is inside a higher order of specificity, add the rule in your css:

http://jsfiddle.net/yQEQJ/2/

```
/** This takes effect, overriding the 
    text color inside your button, since its' wrapped in p 
**/
.landingpage_create_group_button:hover.groups_landingpage_contentdiv_text p button.landingpage_create_group_button p
{
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #6F862A;
}

/** add this rule **/
button.landingpage_create_group_button:hover p {

    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: @Tats_innit eh? Which my fiddle does right? :o, let me double check lol. Thanks!

Comment: @Tats_innit you are right :s, will delete my answer in a moment

Answer (score 2):

Here's an update on Tats_innit's solution. Two improvements:

1. Hover on div, but change text of p
2. Store old text value to prevent 'information' duplication

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fBjJ/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.landingpage_create_group_button').hover(function(){
           if ( ! $(this).data('oldtext') ) $(this).data('oldtext', $('p', this).text()) ;
           $('p', this).text('Changed on mouseover');
    },function(){
        $('p', this).text( $(this).data('oldtext'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2fBjJ/  **or** http://jsfiddle.net/2fBjJ/4/ (courtsey @NiftyDude)

**Text Color change Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2fBjJ/8/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/2fBjJ/10/

On hover your text will change in the button and on mouse out it will set back to normal.

Hope this helps, let me know if I missed anything!

**code**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.landingpage_create_group_button p').hover(function() {

            $(this).text('Changed on mouseover');

        }, function() {
            $(this).text('Create A Groups');
        });
    });​
​
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.landingpage_create_group_button').hover(function() {

        $(this).find('p').text('Changed on mouseover');

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('p').text('Create A Groups');
    });
});​
```

Comment: `'.landingpage_create_group_button p'` selector selects only `<p></p>` part, but no whole button.

Comment: Hiya @webbandit yep thats why I am just changing the text not html; let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: See my solution for a fix on this

Comment: I mean hover function should be invoked when hovering whole button, not only paragraph part of it

Comment: `$('.landingpage_create_group_button').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('p') // rest of your code`

Comment: @webbandit aa now I got you but as he mentioned text only I thought why not text only

Comment: @Jochem bro good use of my demo fiddle, but doesn't work on first 2 hovers, just mentioning. :)

Comment: @NiftyDude brilliant yep, thats another one, but will be same like above innit; <d'uh lil diff> B-) you submitting your code or should I make change in my demo :) ?

Comment: @Tats_innit weird, works for me all the time, in Chrome & FF on Linux

Comment: @Jochem Yep I should wait until it load bro giving you +1 man **thou shall note** :) and with Nifty's suggestion I have done another version :)

Answer (score 1):

To change text of DOM element (in your case button) you should use javascript. jQuery fits well.

**For example:**

```
$(".landingpage_create_group_button").hover(
  function () {
    $(".landingpage_create_group_button > p").html('one');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".landingpage_create_group_button > p").html('Create A Group');
  }
);
```

Comment: this will change the text in all the buttons with class `.landingpage_create_group_button` with `p` inside, not just the hovered one

Comment: Hmm maybe `$(this + " > p")`?

Comment: close, you can use `$('p', this)`, read the part with `Selector Context` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.landingpage_create_group_button').hover(function() {
    $('p', this).text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText == 'Create A Group' ? 'mouse hover' : 'Create A Group';
    });
});
```

And to change the color try this css:

```
button.landingpage_create_group_button:hover p {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEQJ/8/)**