# [IE7][CSS] Moved elements keep their hover state

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

If I move an element out of my cursor via JS, this element keep its hover state.
I can't reproduce this issue on IE11 or Chrome.

```js
function moveElement(e) {
  var first = document.querySelectorAll(".aTab")[0];
  e.parentElement.insertBefore(e, first);
}
```

```css
#tabBar {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  height: 60px;
}
.aTab {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.aTab:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabBar">
  <div class="aTab" onclick="moveElement(this)">1</div>
  <div class="aTab" onclick="moveElement(this)">2</div>
  <div class="aTab" onclick="moveElement(this)">3</div>
</div>
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

IE7 won't allow you to apply `:hover` pseudo-classes to non-anchor elements unless you explicitly specify a doctype. Just add a doctype declaration to your page and it should work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

More on IE7/quirks mode can be found on this [blog post](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762).

[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/pseudo-class-hover-does-not-work-in-ie7)

Comment: The pseudo-class `:hover`is taken into account. The issue is that IE does not realize that the cursor is not over the item if I move the element in the DOM.