# Problems with jQuery hover() in IE7-8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm using jQuery to add a class to some elements on hover() in order to add some additional styling, but somehow it's not working in Internet Explorer 7 - or rather, it seems to be working sporadically on some of the elemets.
(It's for an old SharePoint installation, so I need it to be compatible with IE7 and jQuery 1.4.1...)

I know IE 7-8 have issues with z-index, but I don't know if that's why it's not working here.
It works in Chrome and Firefox.
My markup is this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/488x488?text=Background+image" alt="">
  <div class="pin one">
  </div>
  <div class="pin two">
  </div>
  <div class="pin three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
$('.pin').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
    //window.console && console.log('foo');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbbar0d/) - which obviously won't run on IE7 or 8.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to change the z-index on hover. could you not change it using `.pin:hover` in the css

Comment: have you tried .mouseover instead of hover?

Comment: @Andrew maybe he is generating the content and js is redrawn specific to html structure...just maybe :(

Comment: :hover is not supported by IE 7 except on <a> elements.

Comment: @DincaAdrian > according to jQuery specs, "calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for: `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`"

Comment: Have you declared a proper doc type:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143296/pseudo-class-hover-does-not-work-in-ie7

Comment: @Andrew, yeah, I have that exact doctype... 
Adding z-index on hover was just a test. It didn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried to set a background-color transparent for the .pin elements. IE has some problems detecting positioned elements and setting a bg was a workarround.

Comment: @DincaAdrian, good suggestion. However, it didn't make any difference.